# Infer string literal type from a JSON file

Tags: typescript, string-literals

I am reading from a large JSON file.
TypeScript is smart enough to **infer the types** of all the properties **except one**.

A simplified example:

```
type Animal = 'bear' | 'cat' | 'dog';

const data = {
  name: 'Max',
  age: 3,
  animal: 'dog',
  // 100s other properties from JSON file...
};

let theName: string = data.name; // perfect
let theAge: number = data.age; // perfect
let theAnimal: Animal = data.animal; // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Animal'
```

([link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2UC8UDkAjCFAJxygB9cBjFYUinAEwHsBzHAbgChPKm4BnYFAY0UWKAG9OUKHBRIIALlwBZFAA8cAGmlQULJVADMOmSkSo0yxq226A9PagBGAAyv%20UJsAAWEIlBgREyQRMAIEJ4AZsFIUABSAMoA8gByUFEIaBAAdHmcAL5cnNlCvhCp8oaCRAhwLOIiwCg5cgrsUI6B-lEQlMAlEGV%20MAbKcACuSAQB2E0t%20hAdXaG9-YPDEPDI6Mrblo2iOeY7aMtOAKJEwUTKACrg0Dg1dWxQCJ5w3nr8-Agscjw2SgwCYIMeuH26BwnCAA))

`data.animal` is used in several places, so I'm trying to avoid using `as Animal` everywhere.

What is the best way to fix this issue?
Is there any simple way I can tell the code that `data.animal` is an `Animal`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use sum types and merge 2 definitions - the original definition of your data and the animal:Animal definitions.

```
type Animal = 'bear' | 'cat' | 'dog';

// the keys your want to exert
type DataWithAnimal = { [P in 'animal']: Animal } ;

const data = {
  name: 'Max',
  age: 3,
  animal: 'dog',
  // 100s other properties from JSON file...
};

// original data type
type DataType = typeof data;

// merge the 2 type definitions
type Data = DataType & DataWithAnimal;

// cast old type to new type
const typeData: Data = data as Data;

let theName: string = typeData.name; // perfect
let theAge: number = typeData.age; // perfect
let theAnimal: Animal = typeData.animal; // also perfect
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @kirin nee!! Do you mind explaining the `[P in 'animal']` bit?

Answer (score 0):

What about do like this?

```
type Animal = 'bear' | 'cat' | 'dog';

type Data = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  animal: Animal;
}
const data: Data = {
  name: 'Max',
  age: 3,
  animal: 'dog',
  // 100s other properties from JSON file...
};

let theName: string = data.name; // perfect
let theAge: number = data.age; // perfect
let theAnimal: Animal = data.animal;
```

Comment: Um... thanks but we're talking about a 339-lines JSON file here...