# Mapping an imported JSON file's string property value to an enum with TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript, enums

Let's say I have the following JSON:

```json
[
  { "type": "one", "tile": { "x": 0, "y": 0 }},
  { "type": "two", "tile": null }
]
```

and I import it into a TypeScript module:

```
import dataJson from "data.json";
```

If I write `type T = typeof dataJson;` then `T` is defined as:

```
type T = ({
  type: string;
  tile: {
    x: number;
    y: number;
  };
} | {
  type: string;
  tile: null;
})[]
```

However, what I really want is this:

```
enum Type {
  one,
  two
}

interface Entry {
  type: Type,
  tile: {
    x: number,
    y: number
  } | null
}

const data: Entry[] = dataJson;
```

Unfortunately, TypeScript complains about this:

> Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FeatureType'. ts(2322)

I know *why* this is happening, but I can't seem to find a way around it. Is there a way to somehow coerce the auto-generated `typeof dataJson` into `Entry`?

Comment: Why use `type: keyof typeof Type` instead of defining `enum Type` as a string-enum, (e.g. `enum Type { one = "one", two = "two" }`) and then `interface Entry { readonly type: Type; }`.

Comment: In this case I would just go `const data: Entry[] = dataJson as any`.

Comment: @hackape That's a horrible use of `any`.

Comment: @Dai and why is that?

Comment: Because the `any` type should be avoided as much as possible: it's unsafe and means you lose compiler-enforced type safety.

Comment: That’s general rule yeah. But what exactly is unsafe in this specific case? And do you have a better solution? Cus string enum doesn’t really help OP’s problem.

Comment: @NathanAldenSr I found this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69565782/infer-string-literal-type-from-a-json-file) might help.

Comment: This pb is similar to how TS would handle type inference of object literal. By default, `{ foo: "bar" }` is `{ foo: string }` unless annotated `as const`. Reasonable cus it’s a big perf penalty to infer string literal type everywhere.

Comment: Same rule applies to json. If you have specific value which you want TS infer as string literal, you need to explicitly tell it. Unfortunately `as const` is not possible in json, so the clever type merging technique in that linked question is a good option.

Comment: I personally don’t have any pb to use `as any`. I mean, at the end of day, we as coders OWN our code and data right? It’s our job to make sure type annotations are correct. I am definitely not afraid to go off-guard from TS’s babysitting in this kind of situation, as long as I understand the impact.

Comment: I refined my question.

Comment: Can someone help me by adapting the linked answer to my code? If you submit it as an answer, and assuming it works, I'll mark it as the answer. Also, I was not able to get the suggested `as any` to work, I suspect due to the `string` -> `enum` conversion.

Comment: This is not just a simple type conversion - the enum currently has numbers as values. You have to convert that at runtime or change the enum to have string values.

Comment: @pascalpuetz Whoa, yes! Changing the enum to have string values did work when combined with the `as any` approach.

Answer (score 1):

You don't like `as any`, understood. How about `as Entry[]`?

```
type Entry = (typeof dataJson)[number] & { type: "one" | "two" }
const data = dataJson as Entry[]

// as oppose to
const data: Entry[] = dataJson
// which still gives you error
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggUhcMC8MDaAoGGAbxgCIoBPABwFNSAuM8OgGjKgEsAbOxk0gB4MYABjakKwkTAC+MlgWLtqvdgHcQpcZx7CwAVy5dZeALp48lWjACiYKACcKWGAAorNEADN4SVOjAAShwDAFsAIxoHUxgAMiUPRlJmUhgAH3VNE1BIWERkF3z-DAQIW3snHHM8GjCYAGVHO31QgBUVYkVCZhcAcmZehUJCKA0+0ZBevBkLIpwRUwA6Dz6BvDmF5Y7sXompjaWVnagACwcaGn2-ecPthqaw9tpF5nXrzaP7h2a2lWWNWbvQ7cGguAxGN7IG7LEEuEgCRgARjYFEYACY2AAvRgAZhMBxhPDhMFRMF6aN6JiAA)

> It seems to me you're not familiar with enum in TS, I also include some [side note](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFMDsFcFtQEYE9QBNwDMCG0A2AXUaAZ3FBlgXACdQtjQA3LXacAKCjlADk4BRCqADe7UKAD2kcABpQIUAAYxofAHcJchQEZ2AX3bsFFGgEsAxhCHNWZAFSnid0MWgJ8SAA5l8E8nCpaD292XHBCLAAuf0oaUABeXgEKADopMgUAcwkJVFDwxGjFBKTYQTg06XkwbNz8wgRtaO0SvjLU9OrELFQ5GmoJWnMcTIALfEMFAEEAFRn+HhmASQB5HgBCTaMwfFHHF1GJPFREMnMpYlN0anATrBdvc1MWUGHSbbpIE88BhCwEXAoYiHY6QADkDTIUHO0GoWEyt3qr2ibXK8ESxQUMwAyqApgAZfErADquPol0ykFMkEyMUCqj8JmoFis3GCHDChFQKOS3ESABYusNGOAsPhojjXlhIJAJIRhvhzKNVHsGP1BpMwFxYAwsDdVF4OApUKYMBhWfB2aB9rL5RJYJ4xaYAT4-KKlZJdjROEIVl7qKihKJxOJoLKZCpxKgJMQIwYkQAPHntPmlNEpdQSdgJkp+0Y0QMVaMMBTgEWQa3mr2mWjUMP4UywMg2Ni6-VelxYJuGD5II5SivgBOeXAWUz4QFEUgufDMml0Bgtjja0DY2dokQqTqJMHpMER8SZkoQjT7-SGNfUdPb+I7vdI8DRYiz6m0xKX69VLI5PKc0AYaJd2kMESg-DovxqH9NTxOYFmWNZNnWD4w1HABrMgmRZbU5ElaNwGIcEIlwXAJDUBcKQrZ851pUd8BoF5fBnaiLSRTJojA1MgPAED6FeC4Jj-TImlXdchDvYCFxEq8hAUBBoEIPtoD444pWfa1CFgaUYBYQFWIAJnY0TOMyZ1AkcUYeIYDj4AUQ41DLGgcNxYYZTlKVFWVXZ9nVah2CAA) on the topic (optional reading material).

Comment: This does work, but it doesn't quite get all the way there. I'd really rather expose `type` as `Type` instead of literal strings. It seems like the only way to do this (so far) is to use `as any` combined with a string-valued enum, as @pascalpuetz said.

Comment: Just like to mention that, “string enum” is very diff from “string literal” from TS’s perspective. A type system nerd would tell you, “string enum” is subtype to “string literal”, i.e. enum *is* literal, but it’s more *specific* than literal. Thus, if you type your field as `type: Type`, it’s bound to a more specific constraint, and thus string literal is no longer assignable to this field, which explains your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, so far, the only way to do this is the following (thanks to @hackape and @pascalpuetz for getting me there):

```
import dataJson from "data.json";

enum Type {
  one = "one",
  two = "two"
}

interface Entry {
  type: Type,
  tile: {
    x: number,
    y: number
  } | null
}

// "as any" seems to be the only way to coerce `type: string` to `type: Type`
const data: Entry[] = dataJson as any;
```

I'm okay with `as any` in this case since JSON is fundamentally much more weakly typed than TypeScript anyway.